# Vim + cscope: how to make Ctrl-] to always jump to first result

Tags: vim, cscope

When I use ctags in vim, `CTRL-]` always jumps to the first result.  In the same code base, with cscope enabled in vim, `CTRL-]` no longer jumps directly, but instead gives me a selection (like `:ts`). How can I make it jump to the first result by default? I use `:ts` later when I need.

Comment: I would be curious, too, but I'm afraid that's how cscope integration works in Vim.

Comment: I have never used cscope myself. But maybe you could use something like `au BufEnter *.c :nnoremap <buffer> <C-]> <C-]>1<CR>`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @Daan no, it doesn't work for two cases: when there is no match, or too many matches (over a page).